# Running C compiler using fexecve

Tags: c, linux, file, compiler-errors, system-calls

For an assignment, I'm trying to compile a program using fexecve. The relevant code:

```
/* compile */
char* compiler_envp[] = {NULL};
char* compiler_argv[] = {"/usr/bin/cc", "math.c", "-o", "math", NULL};
int compiler_fd = open("/usr/bin/cc", O_RDONLY);
if (fexecve(compiler_fd, compiler_argv, compiler_envp) < 0) {
    printf("Could not compile math program\n");
}
```

My expectation is that my code will execute the c compiler and compile math.c.

However, I am receiving the following error message:
`collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld' compilation terminated.`

I have ld installed. The output of whereis ld is the following: `ld: /usr/bin/ld /usr/share/man/man1/ld.1.gz /usr/share/info/ld.info.gz`

Could anyone help me to understand how to get this working? I suspect it is an issue with how I've structured my compiler_argv.

Thanks!

Comment: You're passing an empty environment. `cc` uses `execve()` to run `ld`, and it needs to find it using the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: If you don't need to change the environment, you should pass the same environment you received, not an empty environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Barmar,

Got it working (included unistd.h to access environ).

```
/* compile */
extern char** environ;
char* compiler_argv[] = {"/usr/bin/cc", "math.c", "-o", "math", NULL};
int compiler_fd = open("/usr/bin/cc", O_RDONLY);
if (fexecve(compiler_fd, compiler_argv, environ) < 0) {
    printf("Could not compile math program\n");
}
```